# how to develop simple web api using ASP .net core webapi?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to .net core, I'm trying to build a calculator web API. I struggling to find the exact way to do this. I managed to build API controller part with multiple get methods which return math operation. Below is the code

```
//MathController.cs file.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Calculationwebapi.Controllers
{
    public class MathController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int Add(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 + value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int Substract(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 - value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int Multiply(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 * value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public int Divide(int value1, int value2)
        {
            return value1 / value2;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "default";
        }
    }
}
```

What must be the project structure and how should I proceed next? Do I need to build model and view file as in .net core MVC? i built this in .net web API just by creating a web API server with API controller and configuring web api I used json to consume web API server. In .net core both MVC and web API are together so I'm little bit confused doing in .net core

Comment: looks like your project is not yet a .Net core API app, as 'APIController' is used here. You can try to follow the well written doc from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score -1):

For creating a web api in .net core you must have have a db class where you have written all the linq operqation to fetch data after that just right click on sollution and add new project than go to web and select ASP .net web application and after that select an empty tempelate and dont forget to check the web api and after that you are ready to go write your web api.